# How to select a batch from a preloaded dataset in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I have a large dataset which can fit into GPU memory, and I would like to select a random batch from it in each step of the training. The dataset consists of two arrays:

```
data1 = np.load("data1.npy")
data2 = np.load("data2.npy")

t_data1 = tf.constant(data1)
t_data2 = tf.constant(data2)
```

`data1` and `data2` has a shape `(16000, 200)`. The batch size is 128, so I would like to select 128 elements from each array with the same indices, and provide it to the optimizer:

```
for i in range(training_steps):
    choise = np.random.choice(data1.shape[0], batch_size)

    X_batch = t_data1[choise]
    Y_batch = t_data2[choise]

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: X_batch, Y: Y_batch})
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes
```

What do I wrong? How is it possible to generate batch from the data, which is already on the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

`t_data1` and `t_data2` are constants in tensorflow. You can do this in numpy, but tensorflow doesn't support advanced indexing, you need to use `tf.gather()`.

Change to:

```
X_batch = tf.gather(t_data1,choise)
Y_batch = tf.gather(t_data2,choise)
```